# Eclipse:Cannot connect to database. Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets

I know this question has been asked before but it is not a duplicate. I have included the mysql connector jarfile to the projects build path(thus the answers to this previously asked question does not help). The connection works when calling my database class using a test driver, but it does not work when using a servlet with tomcat. I am really not sure what the issue is. Here is my code for my constructor which creates the db connection for mysql:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseManager {
private Connection con;
private Statement st;
private ResultSet rs; 

public DatabaseManager()
{
    System.out.println("Connecting to database");
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase","username","password");
        st=con.createStatement();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot connect to database. Error: " + e);
        return;
    }
 System.out.println("Connection Successful");
}
}
```

I call this constructor in a testdriver(using the main method entry point) and the connection works(no exceptions are thrown). However when attempting to call this same class in a servlets doPost() method(using the servlet class api), I get the error labeled above. The servlets code is simply:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
DatabaseManager manager = new DatabaseManager();
}
```

Both the testdriver, the servlet and the DBManager are in the same project. I only was using a testdriver for testing purposes.

Comment: Build path is **not** the same as classpath

Comment: What would you recommend me doing instead then? New to eclipse but everywhere I've looked told me to add the jar to the projects buildpath

Comment: add it to your classpath as well

Comment: Ya thats my issue. Sorta a noob with this haha. How would you add to a classpath in eclipse. I only see the option to add it to buildpath.

Comment: I currently have the jar file in the referenced libraries section of my project